# Linked Lists Crashing Down after accepting the first number

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

```
struct node
{
int value;
struct node* nextptr;
};

typedef struct node Node;
typedef struct node* Nodeptr;

Nodeptr* currentptr = NULL;
Nodeptr* previousptr = NULL;
Nodeptr* startptr =NULL;

void insertnode(int data)
{

Nodeptr newptr;
newptr = (Nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
newptr->value = data;
newptr-> nextptr = NULL;

(*currentptr) = (Nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
(*previousptr) = (Nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
(*startptr) = (Nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));

if((*currentptr) == NULL)
  {
   *currentptr = newptr;
   *startptr = newptr;
  }

else
{
  (*currentptr)->nextptr = newptr;
  *previousptr = *currentptr;
  (*currentptr) = newptr;
}
 }
```

This is the code that I'm using to create the linked lists.

```
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    int num;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    insertnode(num);
  }
```

This is used to get input from the user using a for loop..
int n is declared & initialized already.
My program crashes after getting the first input. I have thought of memory allocation problems but that does not seem to resolve the problem.
Also I'm new to C & programming so please excuse any tiny mistakes!

Comment: Why would `insertnode` have to create _four_ nodes to insert _one_??

Comment: You want `Nodeptr currentptr = NULL` instead of `Nodeptr* currentptr = NULL` and `currentptr = (Nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));`  instead of `(*currentptr) = (Nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));` etc. You typedefed `typedef struct node* Nodeptr`, this is poor practice and only adds confusion. There are most likely more problems though.

Comment: don't typedef pointer types (except function pointers) and [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your code :

> ```
> (*currentptr) = (Nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
> ...
>
> if((*currentptr) == NULL)
> ```

Supposing you had memory to do the malloc and the assignment is valid, the test after is false and is useless

You have globally in your code a confusion between to get/set a pointer and to get/set the pointed value

> My program crashes after getting the first input

Concerning your crash this is just because *currentptr* is null when you de-reference it in the first line above

There are plenty of examples of linked list in C on S.O. I encourage you to look at them using the *search*

If you have *valgring* use it, this a very useful tool, and/or of course use a debugger